# How do I get a book graphic and description from the Amazon Book API?

Tags: amazon-web-services

[This URL](http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?Service=AWSECommerceService&AWSAccessKeyId=13529AWJ97PJXSM2K1R2&Operation=ItemLookup&ItemId=1590599659) sends an ISBN number to Amazon and gets back a small bit of XML including author, title, and publisher.

However, I also want to get small, medium and large graphic and book descriptions of the title.

Problem: I can find no REST URL examples/documention that work, either at Google or when logged into my "AWS Account" at Amazon Associates.

I find a lot of examples from 2003-2005 but they are all out-of-date and give errors, it seems that Amazon's cloud web services have obfuscated their simple REST API documentation for their books.

Can anyone point me to some documentation on how I can get detailed information about books at Amazon via REST/XML?

Here's what I have tried so [far](http://[http://tanguay.info/web/index.php?pg=forays&id=3][2]).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So, allow me to answer my own question, from another question here I found this [useful PDF](http://s3.amazonaws.com/awsdocs/ECS/20080819/QRC-AAWS-2008-08-19.pdf) and the following [URL](http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?Service=AWSECommerceService&Version=2005-03-23&Operation=ItemLookup&SubscriptionId=13529AWJ97PJXSM2K1R2&AssociateTag=httpwwwcomput-20&ItemId=B0002ZAILY&IdType=ASIN&ResponseGroup=Images) gets images for instance, see "ResponseGroup"

Comment: Note that the [URL shown](http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?Service=AWSECommerceService&Version=2005-03-23&Operation=ItemLookup&SubscriptionId=13529AWJ97PJXSM2K1R2&AssociateTag=httpwwwcomput-20&ItemId=B0002ZAILY&IdType=ASIN&ResponseGroup=Images) no longer works, since it does not contain a [signature](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/index.html?Query_QueryAuth.html) as is [mandatory](https://affiliate-program.amazon.co.uk/gp/advertising/api/detail/faq.html) since 15th August 2009

Answer (score 1):

ResponseGroup is the key, and if you specify more than one (comma separated) the results are stitched together

That is, "&ResponseGroup=Images,Small" returns the minimal details and images about products

Answer (score -1):

I have build some functions to grab amazon xml using php and curl using simple functions just like this:

```
    <?php
function Get_Amazon_XML($tag, $api, $secretkey, $region, $department, $query)
{
$time = time() + 10000;
$method = 'GET';
$host = 'webservices.amazon.'.$region;
$uri = '/onca/xml';
$slug["Service"] = "AWSECommerceService";
$slug["Operation"] = "ItemSearch";
$slug["SubscriptionId"] = $api;
$slug["AssociateTag"] = $tag;
$slug["SearchIndex"] = $department;
$slug["Condition"] = 'All';
$slug["Keywords"] = $query;
$params["ItemPage"] = 1;
$slug["TruncateReviewsAt"] = '500';
$slug["ResponseGroup"] = 'Images,ItemAttributes,EditorialReview';
$slug["Timestamp"] = gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z",$time);
$slug["Version"] = "2011-08-01";
ksort($slug);
$query_slug = array();
foreach ($slug as $slugs=>$value)
{
$slugs = str_replace("%7E", "~", rawurlencode($slugs));
$value = str_replace("%7E", "~", rawurlencode($value));
$query_slug[] = $slugs."=".$value;
}
$query_slug = implode("&", $query_slug);
$signinurl = $method."\n".$host."\n".$uri."\n".$query_slug;
$signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha256", $signinurl, $secretkey, True)); // Get Amazon Signature API
$signature = str_replace("%7E", "~", rawurlencode($signature));
$request = "http://".$host.$uri."?".$query_slug."&Signature=".$signature;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Konqueror/4.0; Microsoft Windows) KHTML/4.0.80 (like Gecko)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $request);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $response;
}
?>
```