# How to get book cover picture through amazon API

Tags: amazon-product-api

I want to get the cover of a book form its ASIN through Amazon API. I use the `ItemLookup` function, but I only get the `author`, `manufacturer` and the `title`.

ie :

```
<ItemAttributes>
<Author>Anna Gavalda</Author>
<Manufacturer>J'Ai Lu</Manufacturer>
<ProductGroup>Book</ProductGroup>
<Title>Ensemble, C'Est Tout (French Edition)</Title>
</ItemAttributes>
```

Comment: Check the MSDN - http://blogs.msdn.com/coding4fun/archive/2006/10/31/912260.aspx

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433104/how-do-i-get-a-book-graphic-and-description-from-the-amazon-book-api Also, interesting article about using Amazon images here:
http://bibwild.wordpress.com/2008/03/19/think-you-can-use-amazon-api-for-library-service-book-covers/

Comment: Use the Images Product Group in the Amazon Product Advertising API.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$track=$_GET['title'];

// Call To Amazon Predefined Class
$client = new AmazonECS(AWS_API_KEY, AWS_API_SECRET_KEY, 'com', AWS_ASSOCIATE_TAG);
$response = $client->category('Books')->responseGroup('Images,Reviews,ItemAttributes,OfferSummary')->search($track);

// To Get Image
<img src="<?php echo $response->Items->Item[0]->LargeImage->URL ?>" width="233" height="300">
```

Comment: I don't think php was ever mentioned