# ISBN Textbook Image Scraper

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, web-scraping, asp.net-4.0

I'm looking for a way to get images of the cover of a textbook (based on [ISBN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isbn)) on the fly.

I was thinking of parsing the html from:

Amazon

```
http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?&field-keywords=[INSERT_ISBN_HERE]
```

or

Google Image Search

```
https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=[INSERT_ISBN_HERE]
```

(Example ISBN: 9781402778278)

but aside from being against their TOS, it seems very inefficient and they probably have something to block the IP of my server if I keep doing it over and over.

Does anyone know of an open source library or other method/API to find images of textbook covers?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/876758/how-to-get-book-cover-picture-through-amazon-api (@Greg: Link might be useful to you)

Comment: @SimpleCoder thanks, I'll check out the [Amazon Product Advertising API](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/RG_Images.html?r=6802)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/RG_Images.html?r=6802